# WebRequest does not reply on REST url but works fine on others

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, httpwebrequest

I have the following code.
When my URL is google.com I get a proper reply from my WebRequest but when I give the URL of my REST API request my response returns null.

I use the same URL on my browser, it returns the correct response.
p.s.The code I hid with ######### is actually the key to my API that I'd rather not reveal.

```
//HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://#########:@se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/1/10");
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream S_DataStream;
StreamReader SR_DataStream;
string s_ResponseString = "nothing";
if (res != null)
       {
        //Translate data from the Web-Response to a string
        S_DataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        SR_DataStream = new StreamReader(S_DataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        s_ResponseString = SR_DataStream.ReadToEnd();
        S_DataStream.Close();
       }
Console.WriteLine(s_ResponseString);
```

Comment: Get Fiddler and see what's actually happening with the request as you're not really giving us enough information. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ What is the web service actually returning?

Comment: the JSON code of the reply.

Comment: @mattmanser i have installed fiddler. so how do i know what's going on?

Comment: Make a request with your browser, then make a request with your code, are they the same? Does one return an HTML error instead?

Comment: @mattmanser now the browser is giving me an error but my program is not.

Comment: [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "@se.api.anpdm.com" failed.

Comment: that's the answer from my firefox now. it wasn't like this before i installed fiddler. i use the same request with google chrome and it gives me the information i want.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I shouldn't have put the authentication key like that (###) in the url. I should have used credentials like this with the key as the username and an empty password.

```
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("#####################","");
```